# Create a csv from website by python scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to have a csv file of the table in this website. https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/arbitrage/futures-spot-near-2.html

The desired output is a pandas dataframe with columns..
Company,Future,Spot,Basis,Basis%,Previous,Basis,Change,Lot Size

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/arbitrage/futures-spot-near-2.html'


df = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]


df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Company',
                   'Futures': 'Future',
                   'Spot': 'Spot',
                   'Basis': 'Basis',
                   'Basis%': 'Basis%',
                   'Previous': 'Previous',
                   'Basis.1': 'Change',
                   'Lot Size': 'Lot Size'}, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('futures_spot_near.csv', index=False)
```

I tried this but only get the column names in csv

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you forgot to include your code? You told us what you want, but not what you have done to achieve the goal and what problem you cannot solve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get that data:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/fno/marketstats/arbitrage/futures-spot-near-2.html'


df = pd.read_html(url)[1]

df.columns = ['Company','Future','Spot','Basis','Basis %','Previous Basis','Change','Lot Size']

df.to_csv('futures_spot_near.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal (also saved as csv):

```
    Company Future  Spot    Basis   Basis % Previous Basis  Change  Lot Size
0   LTIM    5150.00 4691.60 458.40  9.77    379.35  79.05   150
1   INDIACEM    201.40  197.90  3.50    1.77    0.80    2.70    2900
2   ADANIENT    1860.00 1846.95 13.05   0.71    3.00    10.05   250
3   BIOCON  244.00  242.35  1.65    0.68    0.50    1.15    2300
4   SHRIRAMFIN  1287.10 1278.60 8.50    0.66    -14.95  23.45   600
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
188 MRF 88340.05    89070.90    -730.85 -0.82   -463.40 -267.45 10
189 MGL 893.60  901.35  -7.75   -0.86   -6.35   -1.40   800
190 BALRAMCHIN  359.55  363.55  -4.00   -1.10   -0.65   -3.35   1600
191 ITC 366.45  371.35  -4.90   -1.32   -4.25   -0.65   1600
192 CHAMBLFERT  293.80  298.20  -4.40   -1.48   -3.60   -0.80   1500
193 rows × 8 columns
```